# Trying to add a JavaFX shape from another class and create it in my main class. The Class cannot be converted to node

Tags: java, javafx, methods, constructor, inner-classes

I'm very new to Java. I've been using it for the last two months. The end goal of my code is to try and create a shape and add it to the window without having to set all the properties of the shape in the main "view" class.

When I attempt to add my work in progress Castle class, Intellij is telling me I need to provide a node instead. Below I will provide the class where I'm setting the properties of the shape and the main class where I get halted trying to add it to my window.

```
public class Castle {
    private int width = 1280; // width of the window
    private int height = 720; // height of the window
    private double x, y, size;
    private int denizens;
    private Color color;
    private String name;
    private Random rn = new Random();

    // constructor
    Castle() {
        x = 50;
        y = 50;
        size = 10;
        color = Color.GRAY;
        name = "Anthony's Castle";
        denizens = rn.nextInt();
    }
    // GraphicsContext method
    protected void draw(GraphicsContext gc) {
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(x, y);
        rec.setX(100);
        rec.setY(100);
        rec.setWidth(100);
        rec.setHeight(100);
        rec.setFill(Color.RED);
    }
    // get methods
    public int getDenizens() {
        return denizens;
    }
    public double getSize() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

```
public class TwoDomains extends Application {
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1280, 720, Color.BEIGE);

        Castle castle = new Castle();

        root.getChildren().add(castle);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Village");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Castle isn't a Node and it's draw method seems to be based on using a Canvas instead of the node heirarchy in the Scene graph.  If you want Castle to be a Node composed on other Shapes you might want it to be a Group.

Comment: Or just make the `draw()` method return the rectangle, and add that rectangle to the scene graph...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only add `Node`s to the scene graph, and your `Castle` class is not a node.

Your `draw()` method looks strange. It creates a `Rectangle` (which is a `Node`), but doesn't do anything with it. It also takes a `GraphicsContext2D` as a parameter, which looks like you're going to draw on a canvas, but you don't have a canvas.

You just need to organize the code so that, one way or another, your `Castle` class provides some kind of `Node`.

One way is to refactor your `draw` method as

```
public Node draw() {
    Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(x, y);
    rec.setX(100);
    rec.setY(100);
    rec.setWidth(100);
    rec.setHeight(100);
    rec.setFill(Color.RED);
    return rec ;
}
```

and then replace

```
    root.getChildren().add(castle);
```

with

```
    root.getChildren().add(castle.draw());
```

Note that with this setup, each time you call `draw()` on a single `Castle` instance will create a *new* `Node`, which may or may not be what you want, but it is a very simple task to refactor it if it's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want:

```
public class Castle extends Group {
    private int width = 1280; // width of the window - does EACH castle need a separate copy of this info?
    private int height = 720; // height of the window
    private double x, y, size;
    private int denizens;
    private Color color;
    private String name;
    private Random rn = new Random();  // This probably should be static, or somewhere else.

    // constructor
    Castle() {
        x = 50;
        y = 50;
        size = 10;
        color = Color.GRAY;
        name = "Anthony's Castle";
        denizens = rn.nextInt();
        makeShape();
    }

    protected void makeShape() {
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(x, y);
        rec.setX(100);
        rec.setY(100);
        rec.setWidth(100);
        rec.setHeight(100);
        rec.setFill(Color.RED);
        getChildren().add(rec);
    }
    // get methods
    public int getDenizens() {
        return denizens;
    }
    public double getSize() {
        return size;
    }
}
```